# Import a specific bean in JUnit5 without load all application

Tags: java, spring, junit5

I have a configuration class on my project

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    //client SDK configuration build
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
    
}
```

Now I want to use this bean on my unit test class without load all application context

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyConfiguration.class})
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean mybean;

    @Test
    public void methodTest() {
        //use mybean class methods
        mybean.method();
    }

}
```

But I am getting an `NullPointerException` error when run the test (in the line where I invoke mybean definition)

What could be wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

with

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
```

SpringExtension enables the use of Spring with JUnit5. Once you have that, JUnit will call the extension, which in turn will read the Spring annotations.